# JavaScript hoisting function vs function variable

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Here is my javascript code :

```
    console.log(a);
    c();
    b();            
    var a = 'Hello World';
    var b = function(){
        console.log("B is called");
    }
    function c(){
        console.log("C is called");
    }
```

Now here is output :

```
undefined
hoisting.html:12 C is called
hoisting.html:6 Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
```

My question is regarding why c() and b() behaving differently. And b should throw error something like b is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A Function Declaration will be hoisted along with its body.

#### A Function Expression not, only the var statement will be hoisted.

---

This is how your code "looks" like to the interpreter after compiletime - before runtime:

```
 var c = function c(){
      console.log("C is called");
 }

 var a = undefined
 var b = undefined

 console.log(a); // undefined at this point
 c(); // can be called since it has been hoisted completely
 b(); // undefined at this point (error)

 a = 'Hello World';
 b = function(){
     console.log("B is called");
 }
```

KISSJavaScript

Comment: Thanks.  I added console.log(b) & console.log(c) statement to verify your answer. And you are spot-on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Function **Expression**:

```
  var b = function(){
        console.log("B is called");
    }
```

Function **Declaration**:

```
function c(){
    console.log("C is called");
}
```

Function **Expressions** loads only when the interpreter reaches that line of code.On the other side the function **Declaration**, it'll always work. Because no code can be called until all declarations are loaded.

Read more about [Function Declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) and [Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are calling **b** is not defined yet. Your **b** is a variable which contains function, and the time you are accessing **b** it has not been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because declare a function with Function Expression create an anonymous function unless you explicitly provide a name :

```
var b = function() {}   // anonymous function
```

and differently when you declare a function with Function Declaration, you set a name :

```
function c() {}   // c function
```